# Convert SQL Script to Tableau Calculated Table

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I'm new to Tableau and was wondering how I could create a calculated field that would be equivalent to this SQL statement:

Select studentid, min(semester)

I'm trying to get the very first recorded semester for each student.

Thanks

Comment: Read this, is help full https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guided-learning/introductiontodax?tutorial-step=2

Answer (score 0):

```
{fixed [StudentID]:min([Semester])}
```

Try using this in a calculated field.